# Added unique values from array to array in ElasticSearch

Tags: arrays, ruby, elasticsearch

How do I add a string array to an existing string array field in Elasticsearch with the help of script?

The result string array in Elasticsearch must be only contain unique string elements.

I know how to add a value in string array:

```
x = "test"
client.update index:'test', type:'test', id:'1', body:{script:"if (!ctx._source.a.contains(x)) {ctx._source.a += x;}", params:{x: x}}
```

I need the same code for string array

```
x = ["test1", "test2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply concatenate all elements and then find the unique elements as below.

```
  {
       script:"ctx._source.a += x; ctx._source.a = ctx._source.a.uniq;", 
       params:{x: x}
    }
```

The [uniq method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq) removes all duplicate elements and retains all unique elements in the array.

Comment: I tried execute this code. Error:
> {"script":"ctx._source.a += x; ctx._source.a.uniq","params":{"x":["1","2","3","111","222","333"]}}
< {"error":"ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[MissingPropertyException[Exception evaluating property 'uniq' for java.util.ArrayList, Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: uniq for class: java.lang.String]]; ","status":400}

Comment: As the language tag in your question suggests ruby, uniq is a valid syntax for ruby. Whereas the error shows the language as groovy which means the script was being executed as a groovy script and not as ruby code. The default language is groovy. Your solution is essentially the same as my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code solved the problem:

```
x = ['test1', 'test2']
client.update index:'test', type:'test', id:'1', body:{script:"ctx._source.a += x; ctx._source.a.unique()", params: {x:x}}
```